# Date portion should be defaulted to 1900-01-01

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that has different datetime values. How do I select those datetime values with just the date defaulted to 1900-01-01? The time portion should remain as it is.

Let us say the value in table : 
2020-02-08 19:58:18.320

Expected Output : 
1900-01-01 19:58:18.320

Comment: Why do you need this? If you only care about the `time` component you can just use the `time` datatype and not worry about supplying a `date` at all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT CAST(CAST(YourColumn AS time) AS datetime)
```

will do what you need.

Casting as `time` retains just the `time` portion (so `2020-02-08 19:58:18.320` becomes `19:58:18.320`)

And then when casting back to `datetime` the default date of `1900-01-01` is what SQL Server happens to use anyway so giving your expected output.